# Webview won't display url after publishing

Tags: android, android-emulator, webview

I've published an app I'd built for this web site. Everything had been working fine in the emulator but after I published my app and downloaded it I had saw that nothing in the webview was being displayed. The URL loaded, I know this because I could highlight the content on the page. It simply wasn't being shown.

Why would my app not display the url content in my webview, on a phone, when it did so perfectly on the emulator?

Comment: @Able: which version of your phone you checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know where you have done mistake in codings. But possible mistakes i will list out.

Please specify min and max sdk version in manifest file.
For eg:

uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"

And sometimes, in android above 4.0, if you did'nt provide this in activity,

android:hardwareAccelerated="true", the webview will be blank and will not show anything.